# changes not visible on remote branch after push

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a bare and a test repository on the server, and my local repository that was cloned from bare. i also have a **remote/origin/fix** branch tracked by my local fix branch. I made some changes locally, committed and pushed. It worked the first time when i used **git push -u origin fix**, it created the branch with my changes.

Now i have made another commit and pushed it, **git push origin fix**. if i run **git branch -av** locally,  i see the origin/remote/fix branch with the correct last commit, but on the server,  the last commit is the previous one, for some reason.

I RTFM but i can't figure out why this is. Any help very much appreciated.

**EDIT**:on the server, when trying to checkout the **origin/fix** branch i get the following warning

```
warning: refname 'origin/fix' is ambiguous.
```

I think this might be the problem? 
running a **git branch -av** in the testing repo on the server yields:

```
* fix                  a5ed3f6 test1 
origin/fix             a5ed3f6 test1
remotes/origin/fix     df46078 test2
```

How do i fix this, to update the testing repo? i need to propagate the changes from remotes/origin/fix to the fix branch?

also, in this case, origin/fix is the fix branch in the bare and remotes/origin/fix is my local one? or am i completely off track here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "fix" branch in the testing repo has to be set to track the branch in the bare repo as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before, and rather than using the proper interface commands I just edited the refs on the server to remove the unwanted one (in this case someone had created one named HEAD (!), so I did `cd /some/path/to/repo.git; rm refs/branchname/HEAD`).  Crude, but it worked. :-)